# dc.js (version 3.0.7) - unable to plot rangeChart ('focusChart' of undefined error)

Tags: dc.js, dc.leaflet.js

I am having trouble plotting a rangeChart for my lineChart.

```
d3.tsv("demo.tsv").then(function(someData) {
    drawMarkerSelectsome(someData);
});

function drawMarkerSelectsome(someData) {

parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");
    someData.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dd = parseDate(d.txndatetime);
    d.month = d3.timeFormat("%m")
});

xf = crossfilter(someData);
all = xf.groupAll();

// Dimension by full date
dateDim = xf.dimension(function(d) { return d.dd; });

// Dimension by month
moveMonths = xf.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.month;
});

numRecordsByDate = dateDim.group().reduceCount();;
numRecordsByMonth = moveMonths.group().reduceCount();

minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].dd;
maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].dd;

timeChart = dc.lineChart("#time-chart",groupname)
.renderArea(true)
.width(940)
.height(200)
.transitionDuration(3000)
.margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 40})
.dimension(dateDim)
.mouseZoomable(true)
.rangeChart(volumeChart)
.elasticY(true)
.renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
.renderVerticalGridLines(true)
.brushOn(false)
.group(numRecordsByDate)
.x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
.round(d3.time.day.round)
.xUnits(d3.time.days)
.elasticY(true);

volumeChart.width(940)
.height(60)
.margins({top: 5, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 40})
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(numRecordsByMonth)
.centerBar(true)
.gap(1)
.alwaysUseRounding(true)
.colors(['#D62728'])
.x(d3.scaleTime().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
.round(d3.time.month.round)
.xUnits(d3.time.months);
```

I tried to keep the dimension(dateDim) same and changed the group as discussed here ([dc.js - rangeChart bars disappearing when filtered out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750837/dc-js-rangechart-bars-disappearing-when-filtered-out?rq=1)) but I keep getting the following error.

[image]

Not sure what is wrong with the code. I'm using dc.js v.3.0.7 and d3.js v.5.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that `volumeChart` is undefined. You don't show where it is initialized but I am guessing it is not.

You have to instantiate the lineChart or barChart into `volumeChart` before calling `.rangeChart(volumeChart)`

You can still set its parameters after setting up the `timeChart` if you want.

Comment: Ah! Such a silly mistake! I fixed it though. Thanks Gordon.

Comment: Great! dc.js doesn't do much input validation so the error messages can be obscure sometimes...